# Can't access my VPC in AWS console for creating my redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to launch a Redshift cluster. I have created my own VPC `(180.18.16.0/16)` with two subnets:

```
180.18.16.0/20
180.18.0.0/20
```

These are all in Ohio region. I then try to create a Redshift cluster in the same region. However, when I try to list the VPC, they are being listed but they are disabled and I can not select any VPC either the default or my own one.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You have to browse to the Redshift dashboard and create a Subnet Group that contains the VPC's subnet.

1. https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/redshiftv2
2. Config -> Subnet Group
3. Select your subnet to be part of the group.

This caught me out too. I was looking everywhere in the VPC dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

you are using public IP address range for your vpc cidr.

usually the below private up address ranges used to create vpc and subnets

10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (10/8 prefix)

172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (172.16/12 prefix)

192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html

do you have a subnet cluster group, you need to have it created for you to be able to select the vpc.

Reference:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182207

Comment: Are you purposely using public IP ranges

Comment: thanks for the repose. should I add two subnet groups or one should suffice? I think  I should add one subnet group for better efficiency?

Comment: no idea. haven't used redshift before. but according to aws "You must have at least one cluster subnet group" , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-subnet-group-console.html

Comment: I should have created the subnet group for redshift cluster.